# Adobe After Effects CC - stabilize lighting

Tags: after-effects, adobe, lighting

I have a video of an interview. The lighting of the video keeps bouncing light and dark. Would I be able to fix this through After Effects? How would I be able to.

Sorry very new to after effects.

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

I'll assume the camera op was fooling with the exposure?

You'll need to key-frame color correction or AE's Auto Color function may work for you:
https://helpx.adobe.com/after-effects/using/color-correction-effects.html

If you go the CC route it may help to watch the YC waveform rather than the image itself.

The Color Stabilizer effect may also work for you. Here's lybda "starter" explination for it [youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bYqaw39ADto).

Answer (score 1):

To add to what integris said, your main option is to attempt to counteract the lighting changes by keyframing artificial "lighting" in the *opposite* direction of the real-world changes. So when the brightness decreases in the video, you need to add brightness at the same rate.

If the adjustments are fast step-changes (like instantaneously changing the exposure), it's a little easier. Gradual changes like turning up the output of a fill light or pivoting a lamp towards the subject is harder to make look "natural".